# Iterating nested Python dictionaries

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary, iteration

I am trying to collect info from nested dictionaries (loaded from json). I am trying to do that with for loop. I was unable to get a dictionary inside dictionary that is named "players". "players" contains dictionary with player names and their ids. I would like to extract that dictionary. You can find my code and sample of data below.

I was able to iterate through first level to dictionary, but I cannot filter out deeper levels.

I have been looking through other similar questions, but they were tackling different issues of dictionary iteration. I was not able to use them for my purposes. I was thinking about extracting the info that I need by using data.keys()["players"], but I cant handle this at the moment.

```
for key, value in dct.iteritems():
    if value == "players":
        for key, value in dct.iteritems():
            print key, value
```

A sample of my data:

```
{
"[CA1]": {
    "team_tag": "[CA1]",
    "team_name": "CzechAir",
    "team_captain": "MatejCzE",
    "players": {
        "PeatCZ": "",
        "MartyJameson": "",
        "MidnightMaximus": "",
        "vlak_in": "",
        "DareD3v1l": "",
        "Hugozhor78": ""
    }
},
"[GWDYC]": {
    "team_tag": "[GWDYC]",
    "team_name": "Guys Who Dated Your Cousin",
    "team_captain": "Teky1792",
    "players": {
        "wondy22": "",
        "dzavo1221": "",
        "Oremuss": "",
        "Straker741": "",
        "Vasek9266": ""
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each `value` in the outer loop is itself a dictionary:

```
for key, value in dct.iteritems():
    if 'players' in value:
        for name, player in value['players'].iteritems():
            print name, player
```

Here, you test first if the `players` key is actually present in the nested dictionary, then if it is, iterate over all the keys and values of the `players` value, again a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
for team in myData:
    for player,id in myData[team]['players'].iteritems():
        print "player %s has ID '%s'" %(player, id)
```

Comment: I find this answer because:
1) It does not use the code that was present in the question: ("myData") instead of ("dct")
2) It suggests to use "%s" formatting, which is not recommended by python.